# Cannot render image while using props in react

Tags: javascript

```
<img className="cards-image" src={`../images/${props.coverImg}`} alt="Not loaded"/>
```

Can anybody tell me why the image is not loading?

Comment: Probably because the URL you are passing to `src` doesn't resolve to the image and you are getting a 404 error.

Comment: I am not getting an error message though. It's just that the picture is not loading and instead alt text is displaying.

Comment: That's normal when there are 404 errors for images.

Comment: All the other props values are showing except when i render some images. Src has some issues but i cannot figure it out

Answer (score -1):

move your images to public folder and try this

```
<img className="cards-image" src={`${window.location.origin}/images/${props.coverImg}`} alt="Not loaded"/>
```

Comment: not working. Anyways Thanks.